# regex to check url format

Tags: ruby, regex, string-matching

I want to check if my url format is correct, it has some AWS acces keys etc:

```
/https://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/path/file.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=[.+]&Expires=[.+]&Signature=[.+]/.match(url)
```

^ something like this. Could you please help?

Comment: Search: [url regex](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url+regex)

Answer (score 1):

[URI RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#page-50) specifies this regular expression for parsing URLs and URIs:

```
^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?
```

You can also use the [URI module](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.1.0/URI.html) from Ruby standard library:

```
require 'uri'
if url =~ /^#{URI::regexp(%w(http https))}$/
  puts "it's an url alright"
else
  puts "that's no url, that's a spaceship"
end
```

To check for the existence of "some AWS access keys etc" you can do:

```
require 'uri'
uri = URI.parse(url)
params = URI.decode_www_form(uri.query).to_h
if params.has_key?('AWSAccessKeyId')
  unless params['AWSAccessKeyId'] =~ /\A[a-f0-9]{32}\z/
    abort 'AWSAccessKeyId not valid'
  end
else
  abort 'AWSAccessKeyId required'
end
```

Of course you can just use regular expressions to parse them directly but it gets ugly because the order of the parameters may be different:

```
>> url = "https://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/path/file.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=abcd12345&Expires=12345678&Signature=abcd"
>> matchdata = url.match(
   /
    \A
      (?<scheme>http(?:s)?):\/\/
      (?<host>[^\/]+)
      (?<path>\/.+)\?
      (?=.*(?:[\?\&]|\b)AWSAccessKeyId\=(?<aws_access_key_id>[a-f0-9]{1,32}))
      (?=.*(?:[\?\&]|\b)Expires=(?<expires>[0-9]+))
   /x
  )
=> #<MatchData "https://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/path/file.txt?"
  scheme:"https" 
  host:"bucket.s3.amazonaws.com" 
  path:"/path/file.txt"
  aws_access_key_id:"abcd12345"
  expires:"12345678">

>> matchdata[:aws_access_key_id]
# => "abcd12345"
```

This uses

1. The positive lookahead of regex : `(?=..)` to ignore parameter
   order
2. Ruby's regex named captures `(?<param_name>.*)` to identify
   the params from match data
3. Non capturing groupings `(?abcd|efgh)`
4. The matcher `(?[\&\?]|\b)` to handle `Expires=...`, `?Expires=...` or `&Expires=...`
5. And finally the `/x` free spacing modifier to
   allow nicer formatting

Comment: How on the Earth this checks for “it has some AWS acces keys etc”?

Comment: @mudasobwa now it does.

Answer (score 0):

We need a url to work with:

```
url = "/https://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/path/file.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=somestuff&Expires=somemorestuff&Signature=evenmorestuff"
```

We also need to escape a bunch of stuff and do some non-greedy matching(.+?):

```
/https:\/\/bucket.s3.amazonaws.com\/path\/file\.txt\?AWSAccessKeyId=.+?&Expires=.+?&Signature=.+/.match(url)

 => #<MatchData "https://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/path/file.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=somestuff&Expires=somemorestuff&Signature=evenmorestuff">
```